# Why is the second console log not executed?

Tags: javascript

This is the code

```js
const setError = "";

function validate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const exp = RegExp("w+@example.com").test("sfsdf@gmail.com");
    console.log(exp);
    if (!exp) {
      setError = "Email Not Valid!";
    }
    console.log("The value is" + setError);
    if (setError != "") {
      reject();
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

validate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Resolved");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Rejected");
  });
```

When I run it, I get the following output,

```
false
Rejected
```

Why is the second console.log inside the validate function not executed?

Comment: You should also put `let setError=""` _inside_ the validate function, before the `return` statement. As posted `validate` will fail valid emails because a previous call was for an invalid email address.

Answer (score 1):

`setError` should not be a const, when you try to change its value it throws an error and reject the Promise.

```
let setError = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning to `const setError`, it causes runtime error and stop the function execution.

`const` cannot be re-assigned after initialization. Making it `let` solves the problem

```js
let setError = "";

function validate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const exp = RegExp("w+@example.com").test("sfsdf@gmail.com");
    console.log(exp);
    if (!exp) {
      setError = "Email Not Valid!";
    }
    console.log("The value is" + setError);
    if (setError != "") {
      reject();
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

validate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Resolved");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Rejected");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `console.log` is not firing because `setError` is a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and cannot be changed. Changing `const` to `let` should generate the output you expect:

```
false
The value isEmail Not Valid!
Rejected
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not seeing the second `console.log` is because `setError` is a `const`, so as soon as you try to assign to it a new value, it throws an error and it will go to the `catch` block.

Try this instead:

```js
var setError = "";
```